# How do I use group_concat() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT 
group_concat(cu1.cu_inflow_type),count(cu1.cu_inflow_type) 
FROM cs_test cu1
LEFT JOIN cs_test cu2
ON cu2.seq=cu1.seq
GROUP BY cu1.cu_inflow_type
```

**Result:**

```
    ======================================================================
group_concat(cu1.cu_inflow_type)    |    count(cu1.cu_inflow_type)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
001,001,001,001,001,001,001,00..    | 27
002,002                             | 2
003,003                             | 2 
004,004,004                         | 3
005                                 | 1
006                                 | 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The query runs, but it isn't the result I want. I would like it to look like:

```
======================================================================
group_concat(cu1.cu_inflow_type)    |    count(cu1.cu_inflow_type)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
001,001,001,001,001,001,001,00..    | 27
002,002,003,003                     | 4             <-- add!
004,004,004                         | 3
005,006                             | 2             <-- add!
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

'002,002' + '003,003' = 002,002,003,003
I don't understand how to use `group_concat()` in MySQL to get the desired result. Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you want as your actual output. Can you explain a little?

Comment: You probably want to have all cu_inflow_type for same id in same row if it is the case you need WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

You may please use some other field in the group by clause

Comment: Sorry, Can you explain example how i can put SQL?